# Do Japanese use commas or "and"?

Tags: conjunctions, punctuation

In English when we have sentences like

> I ate an apple, pear and orange

we use a comma to separate the words in a list instead of constantly using "and".

Does one use commas in Japanese in a similar way or does one keep saying (the equivalent of) "and" after every word?

Comment: You forgot the comma after "pear".  :)

Comment: TIL: [Oxford comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_comma)